# How to change default screen for touch/stylus when using a dual screen setup on a tablet?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, touchscreen, wacom, stylus

I am currently using Kubuntu 20.4 on the Dell Latitude 5175 2 in 1 tablet. I use the tablet with an external TV connected to use a Dual-Screen setup for web development. Every time I boot the computer, the touch and stylus is shared between the 2 screens. I have to manually go to settings, graphic tablet and specify that I want the touchscreen/stylus to affect only the screen on the tablet.

Is there a way to set the tablet screen as default instead of both screens? If I don't change this every time I touch the screen the cursor moves between both screens which is very inaccurate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For those who use a Dual Screen setup with touchscreen or stylus and face this issue, I found a solution.

https://networks.guru/2018/11/23/using-dual-monitor-dual-touch-screens-on-ubuntu/

It involves creating a script that will run on startup and will force the touch to focus on only the selected screen.

The script only works when booting up and the secondary screen is connected. If anybody knows how to modify the script to include running the script again if the secondary screen is disconnected and connected again that would be great help. When disconnecting and reconnecting a secondary screen through HDMI, the touch/stylus defaults back to both screens instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

same issue on an Thinkpad l13 Yoga.
I use
`xinput map-to-output 18 eDP-1 && xinput map-to-output 19 eDP-1 && xinput map-to-output 28 eDP-1` (Of course, you have to use xinput and xrandr to figure out the correct values for your setting)
to map my stylus to the laptopscreen. I've created a starticon for it in my favourites list, but an automation would be great!

kde-config-tablet doesn't seem to work here

Comment: Hello @Ray-Ven . My knowledge on Linux is a bit limited. Could you explain to me how you made a shortcut to change the mapping?